# How do I make the sidebar not scrollable and fixed

Tags: css, wordpress

I can’t for the life of me figure out how to make the sidebar fixed so it does not move when you scroll on the entire page, on desktop.

It currently has it’s own scroll wheel for some reason and I can’t figure out which part of the css to edit.

I have a @media css element set up for 955px and greater resolutions to show the sidebar instead of the mobile menu.

Here is the website: atceg.net
And the CSS: https://atceg.net/wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen/style.css?ver=5.2.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set

```
@media screen and (min-width: 55em) {
.sidebar {
position: fixed!important;
} }
```

(I would assume in your WordPress customizer)
If you set it to

```
@media screen and (min-width: 55em) {
.sidebar {
position: relative!important;
} }
```

it will stay in one place.

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much, I never tried that with !important so that must have been the issue.